# Showing that vorticity is uniform when strain is zero

Tags: tensors, fluid-dynamics

Suppose the rate of strain tensor e vanishes in some connected region. Show that the flow is a rigid body motion.

What I have done is taken the curl of e = grad(u) + w where u is the vector velocity and w is the vorticity tensor to show that the curl of the vorticity is zero. However, this does not show me that vorticity is uniform...

How can I proceed?

Comment: Any help would be highly appreciated1

Comment: Anyone can help?